# Performing calculations with the ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5850 graphics card

Tags: c++, graphics

I wish to do calculations with my graphics card as the CPU's etc are too slow. I know it is possible with NVidia cards, (CUDA etc) but I can't find anything about using the ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5850 graphics card in the laptop I have. I wish to perform vector addition/multiplication + exp/log functions with floating point. 
Is there any C code that can access the card and put it to work in this way?
The calculations aren't to do with graphics, but would still be sped up a lot by the increased power of it compared to the CPU I expect.

Comment: What you want is OpenCL: http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/stream-technology/opencl/pages/opencl.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radeon cards support OpenCL (aka ATI Stream) and Direct3D compute shaders.

Comment: Well can you point me to a working C/C++ example demonstrating vector calculations using it then?